# Regarding this proof that the union of bounded sets is bounded (generalized metric space)

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Finite_Union_of_Bounded_Subsets

I am having trouble seeing how this proves the idea at all. It says:

$$d(x, a_1) \le d(x, a_2) + d(a_1, a_2)$$
so
$$d(x, a_1) \le K_2 + d(a_1, a_2)$$

So $d(x, a_1)$ is bounded.

My issue is that $a_1$ and $a_2$ are just two points in the parenting metric space. I don't know anything about $d(a_1, a_2)$, and there is nothing to suggest that $d(a_1, a_2)$ has some bound itself. I don't see how this shows that $d(x, a_1)$ has a maximum value if it is not the case that $d(a_1, a_2)$ does.

Comment: $a_1$ and $a_2$ are arbitrarily chosen fixed points of the space. The gist is that a bounded set is contained in a ball of finite radius around any point.

Comment: If a1 and a2 truly are arbitrary fixed points in the space, then how is d(a1, a2) + K2 a maximum value for d(x, a1)? This would only make sense if d(a1, a2) itself has a maximum value, right? And if that were so, then our universe itself would be bounded, and then the entire idea is trivialized. As a real number analogue, it looks like I am saying x is bounded because x <= k + r, where r can be of any value. Then how is x bounded?

Comment: Looks like the triangle inequality.

Comment: @ZapBrannigan Because $d(x,a_2) \leqslant K_2$. The constants $K_1$ and $K_2$ are chosen so that $S_1$ is contained in the ball with radius $K_1$ around $a_1$, and $S_2$ is contained with the ball of radius $K_2$ around $a_2$. Since the latter ball is contained in the ball of radius $K_2 + d(a_1,a_2)$ around $a_1$, $S_1 \cup S_2$ is contained in the ball of radius $\max\{K_1, K_2 + d(a_1,a_2)\}$ around $a_1$.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, that visual does help. So, the bound of the union depends on how "far away" the two subsets are within the metric space. My confusion comes from the fact that there isn't really a limit on how "far away" they can be. So, I think my issue is that while there is no limit to how far away the can be, for any ONE example, there is a definitive distance between the two sets, and the bound for the union is related to that definitive distance, so the union is bounded. Would you say this is accurate?

Comment: Yes (although, nitpickingly, it could be that the entire space is bounded, then there is a limit how far apart the two sets can be). The distance between the two sets can be huge (and, in many spaces you can find bounded sets as far apart as you please), but it is always finite.